# Unable to access Python instance variables inside Celery Tasks

Tags: python, mongodb, celery

I want to have a MongoDB operation in a celery task but im facing some issues while accessing the instance variables.

Heres the code

```
app = CeleryConnector().app

class CeleryTasks:
    def __init__(self, port, docID, dbName, collName, data):
        self.port = port
        self.docID = docID
        self.dbName = dbName
        self.collName = collName
        self.data = data
        self.client = MongoClient(host='localhost', port=port, username='admin', password='password')
        self.db = self.client[dbName]
        print ("CeleryTasks:init")


    @app.task
    def createDoc(dbName, collName, data):
        print ("CeleryTasks:CreateDoc")
        if 'refs' not in data:
            return

        # Here is the error I dont know how to access the client variable here.
        #db = client[dbName]
        print(data['refs'])

        for id in data['refs']:
            doc = db[collName].find_one({'_id': id})
            if doc is None:
                insertedID = db[collName].insert_one({
                    "_id": id
                })

                print (insertedID)

    @app.task(bind=True)
    def createDoc(self, dbName, collName, data):
        print ("CeleryTasks:CreateDoc")
        if 'refs' not in data:
            return

        print(data['refs'])

        for id in data['refs']:
            doc = self.db[collName].find_one({'_id': id})
            if doc is None:
                insertedID = self.db[collName].insert_one({
                    "_id": id
                })

                print (insertedID)
```

As we cannot pass non JSON serializable objects to a Task so passing **db or client** is not an option.

Problem with the first function
**I dont know how to access client inside it. Tried a few things but failed.**

Problem with the second function
It gives an error  **doc = self.db[collName].find_one({'_id': id})
AttributeError: 'createDoc' object has no attribute 'db'
 etc etc**

How to make this work or how to access instance variables inside celery tasks?

Comment: have to go the hacky path?

Comment: is it possible to move `client` to module level?